# Regular expression not matching all items that should match

Tags: regex

Input string "This.is.it.CAT.DOG.MOUSE.HORSE.go"

```
Regex = [ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-](CAT|DOG|MOUSE|HORSE)([ _\,\.\(\)\[\]\-])
```

This only seems to match ".CAT." and ".MOUSE." when it should also match ".DOG" and ".HORSE.".

I assume because the '.' has already be matched, it's ignored from that point forward ?

Thanks
Nigma

Comment: Add the programming language/environment that you are using to run your RE

Comment: Correct, your regex yields the trailing dot after each matched word.

Comment: Regexes typically don't find overlapping patterns. Use positive lookahead for the second dot in order not to advance the cursor.

Comment: You don't have have to escape every character in a character class... `[ _,.()[\]-]` is much easier to read.

Comment: Programming language is C# - but issue still arises when plugging the string and regex into an online RegEx tool (so language/environment agnostic).

Answer (score 0):

Modify this to suit your needs: http://rubular.com/r/10wI5rf1I4.

```
    (?:^|[\[\] _,.()-])(CAT|DOG|MOUSE|HORSE)(?=[\[\] _,.()-]|$)
```